# How to quickly add an arrow to the end of Grease Pencil Stroke?

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm creating an infographic project in Blender and need to quickly create Grease pencil pointer lines. I'm mainly concerned with the arrows at the end of lines, for now I just have to draw them.

But maybe there is some modifier or advanced way to draw some elements at the end of Grease pencil line?